# I am getting 401 error while accessing powerbi workspace report using access token created by app registered in Azure AD in node js app,

Tags: node.js, azure, powerbi, azure-active-directory

I want to generate access token in nodejs app and use that token in REST API's given by power-bi E.g. - GET [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/{reportId}](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/%7BreportId%7D)

But the access token which is created by node app throws 401 unauthorized error while hitting the API with it,

I have given all the power-bi permissions in azure AD to that app but still its unable to do so.

But it still is unable to access the workspace

I have tried giving it all permission and I want to get the reports via access token generated by my nodeJS app

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: To access Power BI workspace report, the access token must have **`Report.Read.All`** API permission.

I created an **Azure AD application and granted API permission** like below:

[image]

Generated **access token** by using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/Report.Read.All
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code:code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

- Make sure to pass the **scope** as `https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/Report.Read.All` or `https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default`

Decode the access token in [**jwt.ms**](https://jwt.ms/) and make sure the scope is present:

[image]

Using the above generated access token, **I am able to call the API successfully**:

```json
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/reportID
```

[image]

I got the **same error** when the access token did not contain the permission to access the reports:

[image]

**If still the issue persists,** enable the service principal authentication to use read-only admin APIs:

Create an **Azure Security group** and add the service principal:

[image]

Enable **`Allow service principals to use read-only admin APIs`** add the security group in the **[PowerBi Admin Portal](https://app.powerbi.com/admin-portal/tenantSettings?experience=power-bi)**

[image]

After few minutes generate the access token and try to call the API.

**References:**

[Reports - Get Report - REST API (Power BI Power BI REST APIs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/get-report)

[Enable service principal authentication for read-only admin APIs - Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/read-only-apis-service-principal-authentication)